# Why is suddenly all the files in git marked deleted?

Tags: git

I have a huge project with multiple submodules. The only thing I did extraordinary today was

```
git reflog
```

And it returned a set of commits.

But now, when after a couple of hours, when I am about to commit some changes, the git status shows that all the files needs to be added again i.e everything is deleted and newly added again.

```
git ls-files
```

returns nothing.
What went wrong? And how can I fix it?

Comment: sounds like the contents of your working directory might have been deleted. you can reset your working directory to the head commit with `git reset --hard HEAD` if you've committed since this occurred, you can reset to the previous commit if you havn't pushed or revert the last commit if you have.

Comment: @LightBender have multiple local changes. I think git stash wont work here, because the entire project would be stashed and the whole project is in GBs. Could git reflog break the working tree?

Comment: you can compare the last few commits to determine where the change occurred, `git diff --stat HEAD~1 HEAD`, `git diff --stat HEAD~2 HEAD~1`, etc. outstanding changes will be tricky if you've previously committed a series of deletions. Stash is an option, but you'll likely get large numbers of conflicts and need to be careful as you stage the changes after they have been applied.

Comment: @LightBender ALL the files are marked as deleted. Comparing HEAD and HEAD~1 is no good, because the problem is with the local changes. STash is not an option, because ALL files will be stashed then. I am sure, there is an easy fix to this. Could reflog have done any harm to the repository?

Comment: @infoclogged - No, running `git reflog` does not damage the repository.

Comment: I assume you have a bunch of deleted files and a handful of modified files?

Comment: What *exactly* does `git status` show?  Is deletion of every file a staged change, and all files are untracked?  Or something else?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger - yes, deletion of every file is a staged change and all files are untracked. Since all files are untracked, just the folders are shown as staged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've asked for clarification in the comments, so if what I've inferred here is wrong I'll update once that clarification is provided.  But what it sounds like you're saying is, the working copies are all present, but `git status` maybe says something like

```
Changes to be committed

  deleted: file1
  deleted: file2
  ...

Untracked files

  file1
  file2
  ...
```

This would indicate that your index was somehow wiped out.  That could potentially happen with some variation of `git rm --cached` or `git reset` maybe.  Or it could be that somehow the `.git/index` file was simply deleted.

In any event, if that's the state of things, you can

```
git add .
```

in the root of the working directory and it should be ok.  You would then be able to see a proper `git status` comparing your work-in-progress to the current commit.

(I am assuming you still have the intended branch checked out; you might want to check that.  Keep in mind you want to be careful with any command that would affect the working directory at this time, as you have uncommitted changes and git can't help you recover them if they're lost before they're committed, unless you go ahead and stash them.)

Comment: Indeed strange, because I can confirm that I neither ran git rm not git reset. However, the things are good now after git add . Additionally from @LightBenders comment, git reset HEAD further helped. I just added --soft ( git reset --soft HEAD )

Comment: @infoclogged : Well, glad you have it sorted out, but for future reference: the command `git reset --soft HEAD` does nothing.  `--soft` means "only move the head, don't change the index or working tree", and `HEAD` means "the head should move to where the head already is".

Answer (score -1):

I was running into this same issue. For me, the problem was the mac optimized storage setting. My mac was temporarily offloading files to iCloud, and git thought these files were deleted.

You can remove this setting by unchecking the "Optimize Mac Storage" option:
System Preferences > Apple ID > iCloud > remove "Optimize Mac Storage" (as outlined [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253219983?sortBy=best)).